# DecorItem data tag in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

While attempting to use the new Llama data tags in Minecraft 1.11, i was confused upon GamePedia's description of the {DecorItem} tag. Can anyone explain the valid values? I am unsure of the valid input, but my guesses are block IDs or byte inputs determining the variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DecorItem` tag is a compound holding item data for the item within the llama's "decoration" slot, highlighted here:

[image: Llama inventory screen, decorative item (red carpet) to the left]

While the decorative appearance on the llama itself requires the item to be any type of carpet, using commands you may insert any item at all into the slot:

```
/summon minecraft:llama ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1b,DecorItem:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b}}
```

[image: Llama inventory screen, decorative item (stone) to the left]

Comment: Thank you! Also, is the tag {Data:<byte>} valid in the DecorItem compound?

Comment: @FungusKing I assume you mean the `Damage` short tag, which would be a yes. It's an item, so any item data will work (minus the `Slot` tag, as there is no list of slots here).

Comment: I haven't implemented item variants as tags before, so i guess I do mean the damage tag

Comment: What is the format of he damage tag?

Comment: @FungusKing The wiki describes the item format here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Item_structure